# Gnome 3.12 compatibility with gnome 13.1

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I just wanted to ask, does the new gnome release fix the compatibility issues that are present in gnome 3.1 for Ubuntu 13.10?

I can't stand unity desktop but I put off installing gnome 3.10 because when I tried it, I had a few issues that resulted in me having to re-install the OS to fix ( i.e. vanishing mouse for example).

Comment: Turns out I was asking the wrong question, should have been asking about Mir and Wayland. Since Ubuntu is moving away from Xorg to Mir and gnome is only going to move to Wayland more completely as time goes on, I can doubt that it can remain compatible. I'm guessing that it will require more of a work around to get it working, am I right in thinking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is solved, well at least it is in Ubuntu 14.04; it can work with gnome 3.10 without issues, just need to download it from app centre, which I'm going to do after I update to 14.04.